# Adding a string to a string pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, string, arduino

Is it possible to add a string to a string pointer in C++?
Not working example:

```
String* temp;
temp[0] = "string";
```

Just like it's possible in:

```
String temp[3];
temp[0] = "string";
```

Before suggesting to just use a normal array or copy it to a different fixed array, the string pointer needs to be returned in a function. Eg.

```
String* SomeClass::toArray(String str)
```

I am also open to other suggestions how I can return an array from this function.

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question. But as you see the question has arduino tag. String is an object of Arduino language that is based on C or C++, but is not really identical to either of them

Answer (score 0):

Independing of what is `String` this code snippet

```
String* temp;
temp[0] = "string";
```

if it is compiled results in undefined behaviour because the pointer temp either has an indeterminate value (if it is a local variable) or NULL and you may not derefence it.

Provided that this code snippet

```
String temp[3];
temp[0] = "string";
```

is valid you could write for example

```
String* other_temp = temp;
other_temp[0] = "string";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't add anything to POINTER, pointer is just pointing to some memory.
You need first to have some instance, like in your second example `String temp[3];` you are creating three instances of `String`.

So `String temp;` will create local instance of `String`, then to get it's pointer you can use `String * tempPtr = &temp;`, but I don't see why you would want that, as you can use `temp` as is... like `temp.clear();` or whatever functions the class `String` has (see it's API).

---

Edit about returning String pointer.

That's sort of unfortunate C++ API design. So who will own the memory of that instance?

For example:

```
String* SomeClass::toArray(String str) {
    String result;
    // BUG, DO NOT DO THIS!
    return &result; // returns pointer to local stack variable
    // which gets released *here*, invalidating the pointer
}

String* SomeClass::toArray(String str) {
    String *result = new String;
    return result; // returns pointer to global heap
    // now if the upper layer of code will not call "delete" on it
    // you have memory leak
}
```

BTW, from the "toArray" name it looks like you want array of String instances, not String pointer. So that functions should be rather defined as `String[] SomeClass::toArray(String str)`, still having the same problem with memory ownership.

---

What I would do is not return an array.
maybe `void SomeClass::toArray(const String & str, std::vector<String> & array)`, filling up the data into `array` vector.

I do not know how much you use C++ on arduino, if std::vector is OK, or not, but having a class for String feels like vector<> will be OK too, especially if you are wasting your stack by passing copy instance of String instead of reference. (unless `String` is some macro/typedef for `char[]`, please, don't tell me that... I mean, even C++ can be written in low memory footprint way, you don't have to hardwire arrays everywhere, if you avoid unnecessary allocation of temporary instances of C++ classes).